# Can I take soya milk into Australia in my luggage?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, food-and-drink

Does any one know if I can take soya milk in my luggage to Australia, and if I need to or is it easy to obtain in Australia?

Comment: I'd agree with Carl on all points.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: You should upvote his answer, then.

Comment: How would you carry it? Unless you're taking a very small quantity, it's too large for your carry-on, and unless you're using packaging that likely exceeds the value of the soy milk by several magnitudes, your jug of milk will explode in the cargo hold. Or maybe you're planning to arrive by sea?

Comment: laughed my head off at the idea of trying to carry a jug of milk all the way to australia, thanks for the laugh russell just what i needed

Comment: @sheilahannigan Not my humour alas - that was Flimzy. I'm in NZ "just across the pond" from Australia. We even have Soy milk here :-). FWIW re cargo holds - they are run at lower than sea level pressures but are still pressurised compared to external conditions. I'd imagine (no guarantees) that most sealed products would withstand the differential. AND I'd always pack them in plastic bags as a precaution.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Octarine ..............

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You really don't need to bring it, soy milk is widely available at most any supermarket in Australia.

You should be allowed to import soy milk if it's commercially packaged, but you must declare it to [biosecurity](http://www.agriculture.gov.au/biosecurity/import/food) on arrival, if you fail to declare it you may be subject to fines.

Comment: thanks very much thats very helpful and answers my query